# compile module attribute in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What does `@compile` module attribute do? As in:

```
@compile {:inline, some_function: 2}
```

I tried to google something and find something but didn't find anything informative ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-compile):

> @compile
>
> Defines options for module compilation that are passed to the Erlang compiler.
>
> Accepts an atom, a tuple, or a list of atoms and tuples.
>
> For the list of supported options, see [Erlang’s :compile module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html).
>
> Several uses of @compile will accumulate instead of overriding previous ones.

Comment: The docs now say that the option affects the Elixir compiler as well, and provide some examples. Dead link in answer fixed.

Comment: How can `@compile` be used to set the `source` attribute to a different name than the file where the module is defined? I tried `@compile {:source, "/lib/somefile.ex"}` inside the `defmodule ... do ... end` definition but it didn't work.